# Can anyone please suggest me a Java code for aws pinpoint Push notification with android

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm trying to send push notification using aws pinpoint service by using Java. I have research a lot but I didn't find any code or example which is used for aws pinpoint push notification with Android platform. Please help me if anyone have any suggestion ..!

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/analytics/getting-started/q/platform/android
The information is available on AWS documentation.
It is generally expected that you do some searching around the web for documentation of the said library before you start asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have gone through this link but this code is android developers. I just want to make simple API with pure java for Android as well as iPhone platform. 
Btw Thanks for your reply.

Comment: So in case you want to use the same code base for both Android and iOS, you should consider moving to Ionic or some such Javascript based hybrid framework and look at that code.

Comment: Pure java API can also be created using a server side platform. There is enough material for using the aws java sdk. Please go through the docs. Surely there are examples that you need.

Comment: Ok thanks @vvs. I'll check it.